# Why the "else if" statement wouldn't work and what's the meaning of ndigit[c-'0']?

Tags: c, if-statement, character-encoding, getchar

I'm a beginner to C and I don't understand this example from the book *"The C Programming Language by Brian W. Kernighan, Dennis M. Ritchie"*

This program counts "**each digit from 0 to 9**", "**white spaces**" and "**other characters**"

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*count digits, white space, others */
int main()
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    int ndigit[10];

    nwhite = nother = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        ndigit[i] = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c >= '0' || c <= '9')
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
        else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            ++nwhite;
        else
            ++nother;

    printf("digits =");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
    printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n",
        nwhite, nother);
}
```

The output of this program on itself, according to the book, is supposed to be this:

digits = 9 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1, white space = 123, other = 345

but when I run it, it's this:

digits = 9 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1, white space = 2, other = 18

Question 1: Why is there a 0 in **ndigit[c-'0']**? I don't understand what it does.

Question 2: Why my "else if" and "else" statements wouldn't work properly? They don't get the right numbers.

Comment: What did you input that `getchar` reads?

Comment: `c-'0'` converts a character that contains a digit to a corresponding number, say `'0'` to `0`, `'1'` to `1` etc.

Comment: `if (c >= '0' || c <= '9')` should be `if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')` (Both  conditions must be true).

Comment: Always use `{` and `}` in conditionals and loops, even for enclosing a single statement. Thank me later.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie The script of the program itself

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I didn't notice my mistake about &&, Thanks!